# 404 Page Not found при использовании loyalty API

Tags: moysklad-pos-api

Хотела использовать loyalty API, но любой запрос возвращает мне «404 page not found».

Ссылка-пример: https://online.moysklad.ru/api/moysklad/loyalty/1.0/counterparty?search=...

Answer (score 0):

Loyalty API - это API, которое должен реализовать провайдер скидок, чтобы его можно было использовать со стороны MойСклад. Т.е. сам MойСклад такой API не предоставляет.